# Remarkable-rails framework requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have those :

```
    1. rspec (2.11.0)
    2. rvm (1.11.3.5)
    3. rspec-rails (2.12.0) 
    4. remarkable (4.0.0.alpha4, 3.1.13)
    5. remarkable_activemodel (4.0.0.alpha4)
    6. remarkable_activerecord (4.0.0.alpha4, 3.1.13)
    7. rails (3.2.3)
```

My remarkable gem for rspec  should work or not with those gems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`Runtime Dependencies` for `remarkable_rails` gem `3.1.13` version](http://rubygems.org/gems/remarkable_rails), I would venture that it should work.

According to that page, the dependencies are:

```
remarkable ~> 3.1.13
remarkable_activerecord ~> 3.1.13
rspec >= 1.2.0
rspec-rails >= 1.2.0
```